# Repair/Recover data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, restore, recovery

I have a big problem with a MySQL database stored on my raspberry (InnoDB engine). I'm not very expert in this field but I'll try to explain to you the problem.

MySQL crash everytime that I try to start it and I need to recover the data stored inside the DB. The error is:

```
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I just tried to start MySQL with the innodb_force_recovery flag from 1 to 6 but it still crashing. From the log I understood that the problem is a corruption inside some tables.

I tried to check my database file with https://recovery.twindb.com/ and it shows that some tables inside "mysql" database need to be recovered and the tables inside "production" database (the mine) are ok, indeed I can see all my data on this website. How can easly recover my data? There is some free tools or script that I can use? I have all files as ibdata01, *.frm, *.ibd

**UPDATE #1:**

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
    #
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

If I try to start mysql without innodb_force_recovery flag this is the result:

```
pc@pc-hp:/$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And this is `error.log`:
https://pastebin.com/eeSuMxBT

Comment: This problem is not related to data damage. It is related to MySQL server settings - it seems socket connections are disabled or MySQL is not started at all. Check my.ini and mysql error log.

Comment: I have updated my question with new details (also the log and the configuration files)

Comment: System tablespace (tablespace which contains info about all system and user objects) is corrupted. You may make a copy of all files for all databases, re-create system tablespace (or uninstall and then reinstall MySQL), re-create user databases, and then re-import all user tablespaces.

Comment: Ok, now I have a clean installation of MySQL. How can I re-import all user tablespaces from the data files?

Comment: Now use ALTER TABLE .. IMPORT TABLESPACE. And see [Moving Tablespace Files While the Server is Offline](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-moving-data-files-offline.html) and all around.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1 (if *.ibd files are good):**

- Backup /var/lib/MySQL folder with all data
- Remove /var/lib/MySQL and initialize the data folder with `mysql_install_db` command to not miss the *.cnf file

  OR
  Fresh install mysql
- Create new database as that one to restore
- Create all tables with the correct schemas (you can recover they with the *.frm files of every table, online there is some tools)
- Remove all tablespace inside mysql with `ALTER TABLE "tableName" DISCARD TABLESPACE;`  (you can do it for every table with a simple bash script)
- Copy all backed-up *.idb files to /var/lib/mysql/yourdb folder
- You may have to set the correct permission to files with sudo `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`
- Import all tablespace inside mysql with `ALTER TABLE "tableName" IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

After this procedure you have all data restored inside your database.

**SOLUTION 2 (if *.idb may be corrupted):**

- Download undrop-for-innodb and compile it
- execute `./stream_parser -f /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`
- execute for every *.ibd file `./stream_parser -f /var/lib/mysql/yourdatabase/your_ibd.ibd`
- create inside YOUR_DB/YOUR_TABLE.sql the CREATE TABLE statement of every table
- execute `./c_parser -6f pages-YOUR_TABLE.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/FIRST_FILE_OF_FOLDER.page \-t YOUR_DB/YOUR_TABLE.sql \ > dumps/default/YOUR_TABLE 2> dumps/default/YOUR_TABLE_load.sql`
- Initialize a new empty database and create all table with the correct schema (you can use YOUR_DB/YOUR_TABLE.sql files)
- Import all data with /dumps/default/YOUR_TABLE_load.sql files

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Undrop for InnoDB](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb) a tool behind recovery.twindb.com.
To recover corrupt database you need to follow steps from https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Parse the ibd file:

```
# ./stream_parser -f /var/lib/mysql/sakila/actor.ibd
```

The dump records from the PRIMARY index:

```
# ./c_parser -6f pages-actor.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0000000000000015.page \
    -t sakila/actor.sql \
    > dumps/default/actor 2>&1 dumps/default/actor_load.sql
```

Then load the dump:

```
# mysql --local-infile sakila < dumps/default/actor_load.sql
```